# Can i open a 32 bit visual studio project in a 64 bit enviroment?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, 32bit-64bit

Can i open a 32 bit visual studio project in a 64 bit environment?

I am running Visual Studio on a 32 bit Windows 7 version. My question is if someone with a 64 bit Windows version can open my project.

I have the Visual Studio 2012 ultimate edition.

I use Visual Studio for web development with C#.

Comment: I have no idea about Visual Studio (is is MS, right?), but what good would a 64bit development environment be if you cannot create something for another architecture?

Comment: This question takes new meaning... if you currently download the free version of Microsoft's visual studio, they ONLY give you the 32bit version, no matter what your operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Visual Studio project files are not tied to CPU architecture.

*Executing* that project is a different matter. If the project itself is a 64-bit C++ application, you will need a 64-bit machine on which to run it, but the machine will still be able to open the project, see the files and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any project on 32bit can be run on 64bit windows. But you cant run a 64bit project on a 32bit windows. Hope you got the answer.

Comment: Question is about the VS IDE rather than the executables that it generates